# JMSListener dynamic destination not working

Tags: jms, spring-jms

If I hard code the value for destination, processSampleMessage execution is happening.

If I try to change it to dynamic one ${ibm.mq.channel}, not executing method. Did I miss anything?

```
@Component
public class SampleMessageReceiver {

  @Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  @Autowired private UrlsConfig urlsConfig;

  @JmsListener(
      destination = "${ibm.mq.channel}",
      containerFactory = "myListenerContainerFactory",
      selector = "JMSCorrelationID='c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040'")
  public void processSampleMessage(@Valid SampleMessage sampleMessage) {
      System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In process SampleMessages ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n");

  }

  }
```

Comment: Works fine for me; turn on DEBUG logging to see if you can figure it out. If you are not using Spring Boot, are you sure you have a property placeholder configurer in your application context?

Comment: I am using spring boot

Comment: Then the destination will become the value of the `ibm.mq.channel` property in application.properties or application.yml.